# Getting FileNotFoundException when using System.getProperty("user.dir")

Tags: java

I am attempting to access a file within my current working directory.

The error I am getting is

```
 [java] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/user/Documents/DataComProject1\confA.txt
```

The line which is causing this, I presume is:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + fileName));
```

Whenever I print the directory I'm attempting to use with FileReader() I get:

```
/u/user/Documents/DataComProject1/confA.txt
```

I believe the problem has to do with the the backslash before the text file name being in a different direction.  Upon looking in the directory I can see the file is there.

Comment: Does the file exist? :P Try to show a more complete stack trace. And that line buffered reader file reader, try to split it to few variables and make sure which constuctor is throwing the error.

Comment: @Joni I'm using eclipse, where the code works, and attempting to run it in Linux.  System.getProperty("user.dir") is /u/user/Documents/DataComProject1 and fileName is confA.txt.

Comment: So, at some point between compiling and running the program the slash just changes direction? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Any advice as far as debugging goes?  I know that the path string being put into the program is syntactically correct.  Any ideas as to how that could change after compilation?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line that gives the error. Check the value of the parameter that will be passed to the FileReader constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the Path library instead of creating the path yourself:

```
Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
                 .resolve(filename);
File f = p.toFile();
```

Comment: Ah, the new Path API for Java 7. SWEET!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how is this different from mine?  I am getting the path via the System.getProperty(), then adding the slash and fileName to the end of it.

Comment: @user2376409 Not sure to be honest - I always rely on the JDK for environment dependent stuff (file system, locale etc) and it just works. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Also: does it work if you manually type the whole path+filename? Can you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem (i.e. 3 lines of code with a String containing the path (explicitly, without using properties) and the line that causes the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Don't write `"/"` to separate path elements, use this instead to get the correct path separator that's appropriate for your platform:

```
File.separator
```

Comment: "/" is appropriate on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `fileName` includes an embedded backslash: it's `Documents/DataComProject1\confA.txt`. Since the backslash is a valid character in a file name, `DataComProject1\confA.txt` is assumed to be name of the file, not a name of a file in a directory.

To fix the file name you have to change the embedded `\\` into the correct separator character:

```
fileName = fileName.replace('\\', File.separator);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + fileName));
```

It would be correct to use the slash `/` as the directory separator on every system, but here I use File.separator because not using a hardcoded value makes the intent of the code clearer.

Comment: fileName is just a string containing "confA.txt".